# Parse Background Job can send a message to all users currently logged in?

Tags: parse-platform

I am new to Parse and I want to know if there is a way to schedule a Background job that starts every 3 minutes and sends a message (an integer or something) to all users that at that moment are logged in. I could not find any help [here](https://www.parse.com/docs/js/guide#cloud-code-advanced-background-jobs) reading the guide. I hope someone can help me here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was in need to push information for all logged in users in several apps which were built with Parse.com.

None of the solutions introduced earlier by Emilio, because we were in need to trigger some live event for logged users only.

So we decided to work with **PubNub** within **CloudCode** in Parse : http://www.pubnub.com/blog/realtime-collaboration-sync-parse-api-pubnub/

Our strategy is to open a "channel" available for all users, and if a user is active (logged in), we are pushing to this dedicated "channel" some information which are triggered by the app, and create some new events or call to action.

This is a sample code to send information to a dedicated channel :

```
Parse.Cloud.define("sendPubNubMessage", function(request, response) {
    var message = JSON.stringify(request.params.message);
    var PubNubUrl;
    var PubNubKeys;
    Parse.Config.get().then(function(config) {
        PubNubKeys = config.get('PubNubkeys');
    }).then(function() {
        PubNubUrl = 'https://pubsub.pubnub.com/publish/';
        PubNubUrl+= PubNubKeys.Publish_Key + '/';
        PubNubUrl+= PubNubKeys.Subscribe_Key + '/0/';
        PubNubUrl+= request.params.channel +'/0/';
        PubNubUrl+= message;
        return Parse.Cloud.httpRequest({
            url: PubNubUrl,         
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=utf-8'
            }   
        }).then(function(httpResponse) {        
            return httpResponse;
        });
    }).then(function(httpResponse) {
        response.success(httpResponse.text);
    }, function(error) {
        response.error(error);
    });
});
```

This is an another sample code used to send a message to a dedicated channel once something was changed on a specific class :

```
Parse.Cloud.afterSave("your_class", function(request, response) {
    if (!request.object.existed()) {
        Parse.Cloud.run('sendPubNubMessage', {      
            'message': JSON.stringify({
                'collection': 'sample',
                'objectId': request.object.id
            }),
            'channel' : 'all' // could be request.object.get('user').id
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. It is only for iOS and Android? No Win Phone support?

Comment: It's both available for iOs, Android, and Windows Phone. Check this link : https://www.pubnub.com/developers/

Comment: BTW why do you use REST instead of JS API if you write a Cloud Code? Here http://www.pubnub.com/docs/parse-javascript/pubnub-javascript-sdk I have noticed `PubNub Parse SDK 3.7.12`. You could use this in your Cloud Code, right?

Comment: Thanks Narek, this SDK didn't exists when I started to code this. Will update late my code with new SDK

Answer (score 3):

@Toucouleur is right in suggesting PubNub for your Parse project. PubNub acts essentially like an open socket between client and server so that the sever can send messages to clients and vice versa. There are 70+ SDKs supported, including one [here](http://www.pubnub.com/docs/windows-phone-8-c-sharp/pubnub-c-sharp-sdk) for Win Phone.

One approach for your problem would be to [Subscribe](http://www.pubnub.com/products/publish-subscribe/) all users to a Channel when they log in, and Unsubscribe from that Channel when they exit the app or timeout.

When you want to send a message you can publish to a Channel and all users Subscribed will receive that message in < 1/4 second. PubNub makes sending those messages as [Push Notifications](http://www.pubnub.com/products/mobile-push/) really simple as well.

Another feature you may find useful is ["Presence"](http://www.pubnub.com/products/presence/) which can give you realtime information about who is currently Subscribed to your "Channel".

If you think a code sample would help let me know!

Comment: Thank for explanation. Yes please add a sample here for all of us needs and will need this. As much as I understand PubNub is a plugin for Parse and it can be used along with all the services Parse has, i.e. I can have a background job that sends a message via PubNum to all user who are *Present* in the *Channel*, right? BTW would be a great sample to show how.

Comment: It's not a plugin. As described by Justin, it's a away to broadcast information on dedicated channel. In our case, as soon as user open the app, we ask the app to "subscribe" to a channel.

Comment: @Toucouleur so how is it related to Parse? Could you please post and example that send message to people subscribed to a channel from a Parse Background Job?

Answer (score 2):

Here's a few ideas I came up with.

1. Send a push notification to all users, but don't add an alert text. No alert will show for users who have the app closed and you can handle the alert in the App Delegate. **Disadvantage**: Uses a lot of push notifications, and not all of them are going to be used.
2. When the app comes to foreground, add a flag to the PFInstallation object that specifies the user is online, when it goes to the background, set the flag to false. Send a push notification to the installations that have the flag set to true. **Disadvantages**: If the app crashes, you would be sending notifications to users that are not online. Updating the user twice per session can increase your Parse request count.
3. Add a new property to the PFInstallation object where you store the last time a user did something, you can also set it on a timer of 30s/1m while the app is open. Send a push notification to users that have been active in the last 30s/1m. **Disadvantage**: Updating the PFInstallation every 30 seconds might cause an increase on your Parse request count. More accuracy (smaller interval) means more requests. The longer the session length of your users, the more requests you will use.

Comment: Thank you very much. So I can send Push notification using background job? The way for server to say something to clients with its initiative is only to send Push notifications (your all solutions assume using it)?

Comment: Yes, you can send Push notifications using a background job. And yes, as far as I know, the only way for the server to send messages to the device is through push notifications.

Comment: Emilion what if I will send a lots of push notifications to the users. Say I send **10 push notifications / sec**  to a player. Will it be blocked by Apple, Android, Windows Phone?

Comment: Yeah, your app might be rejected by Apple, but you'll also reach the Parse notification limit really quick and it will be very expensive for you.
If you want a persistent connection between client and server, you can try using Firebase.

Comment: Does Firebase open a socket between client and server so that the sever can send messages to clients?

Comment: I'm not very familiar with Firebase, but I know that's what we use in my company when we need two-way real-time communication between server and client.

Comment: Also the problem with push notifications can be that they are not being delivered immediately. If I send a push notification to 1000 users I think it may take minutes until all the users that are online will get the notification, right?